Are beings are born into a sex due to their past actions and results?
I read the following on the internet:

So beings are born into a sex due to their past actions and results.

Which Pali suttas explain the above?

I don’t remember any Pali sutta which describes the birth of sex. Logically speaking I have two problems with the statement : So beings are born into a sex due to their past actions and results.
First problem is that who are beings , what is the definition of being , how to you recognize a being ?
Second problem is that what is meant by their past actions ?
In my opinion the correct statement would be under the influence of ignorance birth takes place due to past actions or Sankhara. There is no fixed karmic formula for generating a particular sex as all Sankharas(conditioning) are impermanent.
Therefore  “ So beings are born into a sex due to their past actions and results.” is not totally correct.
